# Applying same directive to many divs in a single component, attaches event listener of that directive to only the last one

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have 50 divs on a single component. I am making a directive named "lazyload". Then I am applying this directive to all those divs. In the onInit of "lazyload" directive, I have registered for scroll event. The eventlistener function of scroll is supposed to check if this div(in my case, all these 50 divs where this directive is applied) is inside viewport or not, and then do few operations on that particular div. But it seems that this scroll event is registered only for the last div of my view.

My component's template:

```
<div class="product-container" *ngFor="#product of allProducts">
            <div class="product-image" 
            [lazyLoadImage]="product.image" >
            </div>
            <div class="product-desc">
                <p>{{product.name}}</p>
                <p> <span>{{product.price | currency:'INR':true}}</span> <span>{{product.monthDiff + " months"}}</span> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The directive "lazyLoadImage" is:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[lazyLoadImage]'
})
export class LazyLoadImgDirective {

    private _el: HTMLElement;

    private _canLoadImage: boolean = false;

    private _imgUrl: string;

    @Input()
    set lazyLoadImage(v){
        this._imgUrl = v;
        if(v){
            this.attachEvent()
        }
    }

    constructor(el: ElementRef, private _utils:UtilServices) { this._el = el.nativeElement;}

    private _loadingDone: boolean = false;

    loadImage(){
      //some operations
    }

    attachEvent() {
        console.log("inside image load dir");
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(() => self.loadImage(), 1);
        window.onscroll = (event) => {
            console.log("scrolling intercepted for: "+self._imgUrl);//log is shown only for the last element where this directive is applied
            if (!self._loadingDone){
                setTimeout(() => self.loadImage(), 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The event listener for scroll is working only on the last product in the iteration.

Comment: Can you make this reproducible in a Plunker? https://plnkr.co/edit/jUgXWx?p=info

Comment: I am trying but its difficult. Can you tell me if there is some method to make different scope for all directives. It seems to me a scoping issue. In angular js 1.x we solved that with isolating the scope for a directive

Comment: No, there are no scopes. I think it should work but there might be some hidden issue. I think it needs running code that allows to reproduce the issue in order to be able to debug the problem.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - Please find the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7X3KeYero0XPVmWsfAu3?p=preview

Comment: You everytime override window.scroll. Try window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) ...

Comment: Thanks @yurzui. Didn't thought of this. Actually struggling a lot in angular2 right now so every error makes me think that there is something wrong with what I know in Angular2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @yurzui said you are overriding the event handler.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QUzBRZJzeGD6aaq6o4oT?p=preview)

I also fixed some other issues in your code (no need for `self = this` if you use `=>` and a few others).

`ElementRef` is `null` because there is no provider for `, private _utils:UtilServices`. Removing this parameter makes `ElementRef` being set.